# What is the difference between "even if" and "given that" in this context?

Tags: meaning, differences

I am doing a CAE, Use of English, Part 1 (Multiple choice) exercise and I came across the following paragraph:

> As nomadic peoples in Asia are known to have been playing the game
>   over two thousand years ago, polo can lay claim to being the world's
>   oldest team sport, **even if/given that** the modern rules were only set
>   down in the 1850s when British cavalrymen stationed in India took up
>   the game.

where **even if** is the correct answer. To me, the latter makes more sense. Why is the former the only possibility, according to the answer key?

Comment: 'Even if', meaning 'despite the fact that' or 'even though some might disagree, using the argument that' **is** correct here.

Comment: The primary assertion in OP's context is *polo can lay claim to being the world's oldest team sport,* - where ***even if*** is used to reference something that ***appears to be incompatible*** with the primary assertion (it's "non-supporting"), whereas ***given that*** references something that ***supports or forces*** the primary assertion to be true. So they have more or less ***opposite*** meanings.

Answer (score -1):

"Given" is a past participle.  What does it modify? One possibility is the noun clause "that the modern rules..."  In that interpretation, the structure is like an ablative absolute - "[the fact] that the modern rules etc. being given." That might work in Latin, but it's awkward English at best.

Another possibility is some unknown referent, making "given" a dangling participle.  Contrast "Given that the modern rules ..., I believe that polo can lay claim..." Here, "given" modifies "I" - I have been given a fact, on the basis of which I have a belief.  Consider "Given no choice, he surrendered." "Given that ABC is a right triangle, [you] prove that the square on the hypotenuse etc."

As a matter of style, at least, to avoid all of the mental gymnastics that goes with sorting out whether a participle is part of an ablative absolute or a descriptor of an agent, I would argue that "even if" is the better choice where the "givee" is not identified.